# Average value of Vout

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, waveform

I have the following circuit:

[image]

where Vin is waveform with the frequency of 1kHz and amplitude 10V. The diodes are ideal. I need to find the average value of Vout.

I found that when Vin > 0 then D1 is off, and D2 is on, so Vout = I1R1 = 1V.
And when Vin < 0 then D1 is on and D2 is off, so Vout = 1 + Vin. Is this correct?

Now I think I need to use

[image]

I tried taking b = 1/f and a = 0 and writing the integral in two parts, one going from 0 to 1/(2f) and second from 1/(2f) to 1/f with. I used the Vout functions I got above in them, respectively, but I get a bad result. How do I do this correctly?

Comment: What result did you get? (Yes, your setup seems okay but you don't show your exact process.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found that when Vin > 0 then D1 is off, and D2 is on, so Vout = I1R1 = 1V. And when Vin < 0 then D1 is on and D2 is off, so Vout = 1 + Vin. Is this correct?

Yes, that's correct.

> Now I think I need to use  \$f_{avg}=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)dx\$

\$f\$ in this sense means function, not frequency. Because this question will give the same answer if the frequency is 1 kHz or 10 kHz, the average will be the same since everything is ideal.

So in order to calculate \$f_{avg}\$ correctly we need to know what \$a\$ and \$b\$ are. I will write it in your way, and in my way.

---

**Your way**

Find out when the \$V_{in}\$ is less than 0, because that's the only time we have to care about it as you stated above in the first yellow box.

If we know that the frequency is 1 kHz and a sine wave, then the period time is 1 ms, from 0.5 ms to 1 ms it will be negative. This is \$a\$ and \$b\$.

\$f_{avg}=\frac{1}{(1-0.5)×10^{-3}}\int_{0.5×10^{-3}}^{1×10^{-3}} 10×\sin(2×\pi×1000×x)dx\$

If we [continue](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(1%2F(0.5*10%5E-3))*10*sin(2*pi*1000*x)++from+0.0005+to+0.001) we get that \$f_{avg}=-6.3662\$

---

**My way**

We want to get a half period of a sine wave, right? Then let's just integrate a half sine and change the sign.

\$f_{avg}=-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}10×\sin(x)dx\$

In my opinion this one is much easier to calculate, I can even do it in my head.

\$f_{avg}=-\frac{1}{\pi}×10[-\cos(x)]_{0}^\pi = -\frac{1}{\pi}×10(1+1) = -10×\frac{2}{\pi} = -6.3662\$

Ahh! Now I see where those numbers came from. No wolframalpha here.

---

We know that half of the time \$V_{out}\$ will be \$1\$ V, other half of the time it will be \$1-6.3662\$.

So the total average for a whole period will be \$\frac{1+1-6.3662}{2}= -2.1830\$ V.

Comment: Just curious, but did you note the OP writing "amplitude 10V?"

Comment: @jonk Gaaaaaaah!

Comment: Oh. And I may as well mention something else that's missing. But perhaps I'll wait until you fix things up and if I still see it missing, I'll mention it.

Comment: @jonk Hit me up Spock.

Comment: Nah. Looking so much better now. You have 3 areas, two of them \$1\times\pi\$ in area and the third one computed good now as \$-20\$. So that's \$\frac{1\cdot\pi+1\cdot\pi-20}{2\pi}\$. And I'm in the same place now. Great!

Comment: So you first calculated average value of Vin when it is negative and then used it to calculate Vout average? Your way is easier, I just didn't realise the result will be the same regardless of the frequency.